# Navigate vim help with CTRL-]

Tags: 14.04, vim

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with default settings for shell. When I use gnome-terminal to open vim help, it does not work when I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> when being on a tag (note that this works with tty1).
Vim help quote :

```
Jump to a subject:  Position the cursor on a tag (e.g. |bars|) and hit CTRL-].
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I have an AZERTY keyboard which is seemingly correctly configured.

Comment: Now, I somehow manage to use that when I type CTRL-ALTGR-].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `gvim`, you can use the mouse to navigate the tags - forward and backward:

- `CTRL-<LeftMouseButton>` jumps to the target,
- `CTRL-<RightMouseButton>` jumps back in the history of jumps.